# Cycle in Scrapy ItemLoader

Tags: scrapy

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#using-item-loaders-to-populate-items

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from myproject.items import Product

def parse(self, response):
    l = ItemLoader(item=Product(), response=response)
    l.add_xpath('name', '//div[@class="product_name"]')
    l.add_xpath('name', '//div[@class="product_title"]')
    l.add_xpath('price', '//p[@id="price"]')
    l.add_css('stock', 'p#stock]')
    l.add_value('last_updated', 'today') # you can also use literal values
    return l.load_item()
```

But if I get from webpage 2 names, prices, etc, how to add it to `l.load_item()` ?

Because I added the cycle but if in the end, I write `return` cycle will work only once.
How to right to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace `return l.load_item()` by `yield l.load_item()`

example:

```
for block in response.css('.blocks'):
    product_name = block.css('div.product_name').extract_first()
    product_title = block.css('div.product_title').extract_first()
    price = block.css('p#price').extract_first()
    stock = block.css('p#stock').extract_first()
    yield Product(
        product_name=product_name,
        product_title=product_title,
        price=price,
        stock=stock,
        last_updated='today'
    )
```

If you use the ItemLoader, you have to reload your variable for each iteration

```
for block in blocks:
    l = ItemLoader(item=Product(), response=response)
    ...
    yield l.load_item()
```

"In the callback function, you parse the response (web page) and return either dicts with extracted data, Item objects, Request objects, or an **iterable of these objects**." [See scrapy documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#spiders)

`yield` is used to generate an iterable of your `Product` Item objects